# Wordpress completely remove custom post type

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I created a custom post type called 'events' a while back. This is no longer required so I have deleted all posts with this post type from the database and from the functions.php file.

I now want to create a page called /events but this still takes me to an archive page which is looking for the posts with the post type 'events', but obviously nothing is found.

Is there a way to completely remove any traces of there ever being a custom post type called 'events' registered? I have even cleared auto-saves too..

Thanks

Comment: Have you added any short-code on `\events` page ? How it will automatically look for the posts of type events ?

Comment: No, I've created the /events page and it is blank, but when I go to view it, comes up with a 'nothing found for this archive' and a search box as if it is still looking for 'events' posts

Comment: Check yout htaccess. Is there any rule over there ?

Comment: Nope, it goes to the /events page fine, but something is telling wordpress that there is still a custom post type called 'events' but there isn't any more..!

Answer (score 0):

If you go into Settings > Permalinks and save those a couple of times it should rectify itself.

Comment: I have unfortunately, I've also tried the `flush_rewrite_rules()` function a few times... still no joy

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleared that custom post type with "trace"

Comment: I mean in "wp_posts" table find the data like "SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_status` LIKE '%trash%'" with your custom post type

Comment: Ah ok, yes, I have removed these as well but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of permalinks. The new page you have created is still getting the permalink of last event post-type. Just edit the event page you have created and below title of page, edit the permalink of event to event1 or anythingelse. Hope this would work for you.

Comment: That will work but doesn't really solve my problem because I need the page to be just `/events` :\